# Remember: eval(XXX_parsed) is much faster than eval(parse(text = XXX))

Tags: r, parsing, optimization, eval

**I update this question based on the comments as it may be useful to other people**

I had a bottleneck in an algorithm I was developing:

```
eval(parse(text = XXX))
```

The outcome I had were millions of text strings with some condition I needed to evaluate.

My question was that `eval(parse(text = XXX))` is 100 times slower than if the same condition is called in the console.

As an example:

```
par_cond <- parse( text = "5.1019344329834 <= 5 & 477 > 0 & -92.8552017211914 < -86.5204010009766")
microbenchmark(console = 5.1019344329834 <= 5 & 477 > 0 & -92.8552017211914 < -86.5204010009766, 
               `eval(parse` = eval(parse( text = "5.1019344329834 <= 5 & 477 > 0 & -92.8552017211914 < -86.5204010009766")),
               keep_source = eval(parse( text = "5.1019344329834 <= 5 & 477 > 0 & -92.8552017211914 < -86.5204010009766" , keep.source = F)),
               par_cond = eval(par_cond))


Unit: nanoseconds
        expr   min    lq     mean median      uq    max neval cld
     console   400   501   538.00    501   601.0   1201   100 a  
  eval(parse 51101 51851 54309.04  52101 52551.5 122200   100   c
 keep_source 18901 19301 19674.13  19601 19901.0  22500   100  b 
    par_cond  1400  1501  1743.86   1701  1801.0   7401   100 a
```

**QUESTION:** Can you suggest any way to make this faster?

**MY ANSWER:**

*instead of*

```
eval(parse(text = XXX))
```

*do*

```
# outside the loop
XXX_parsed <- parse(text = XXX)

# inside the loop
eval(XXX_parsed)
```

**CONTEXT:**

The algorithm I'm developing is a classification one. It consider the position in space and evaluate if a condition is met based on certain conditions and variables. It is very flexible in the sense that an user can input what variables and condition he wants.

The conditions are inputted as text string and the numbers you see above are the results of replacements of text (referring to variables stored in a hash tables) with numbers.

Most of these conditions cannot be evaluated at once as the algorithm starts on a few anchor points and consider only objects adjacent that meet conditions. It keeps on with the evaluation as long as there are new objects adjacent that meet conditions.

Examples of conditions that can be evaluated:

```
condA <- "light > 1000 & between(oxygen, 0.5, 0.8) & elevation < elevation[]"
condB <- "temperature <= 2 & (bias == F | Si < 0.2) & surface > surface[]"
```

Note that the `[]` (e.g. `elevation[]`) means that the elevation of the object considered (e.g. `elevation`) is tested against one or more objects next to it (e.g. `elevation[]`).

**UPDATED APPROACH**:

After posting this question I was suggested to parse whatever condition outside loops and run only the `eval()` command at each iteration.

so for instance imagine the inputs:

```
cond <- "light > 1000 & between(oxygen, 0.5, 0.8) & elevation < elevation[]"
var <- data.table(light = 995:1005, oxygen = (runif(11)), elevation = sample(500:550, 11))
```

The way I implemented it now is to create two lists with all the values needed to evaluate my expression:

```
v_ab <- names(var)[str_detect(cond, paste0(names(var), "(?!\\[|\\{)"))]
v_fn <- names(var)[str_detect(cond, paste0( names(var),"\\[\\]" ))]

for(v in v_ab){cond <- str_replace_all(cond, paste0(v, "(?!\\[)"), paste0("l_ab$", v))}
for(v in v_fn){cond <- str_replace_all(cond, paste0(v, "\\[\\]" ), paste0("l_fn$", v))}

cond_parsed <- parse(text = cond)

> cond_parsed
expression(l_ab$light > 1000 & between(l_ab$oxygen, 0.5, 0.8) & l_ab$elevation < l_fn$elevation)
```

The values of `l_ab$light`, `l_ab$oxygen`, `l_ab$elevation` and `l_fn$elevation` are updated at each iteration and the conditions are evaluated calling

```
eval(cond_parsed)
```

Comment: I don't know if it helps at all but I note that if you replace & by && this can be processed by the Unix `bc` system command: `echo $x | sed -e 's/&/&&/g' | bc`

Comment: Meta programming. Turn your text strings into an R script and source it.

Comment: Well, you should try to avoid storing code in a character value in the first place. Is there a reason why this is necessary? There's a lot of overhead to parsing repeatedly. Generally we try to find strategies that avoid `eval(parse())` but solutions depend on the exact requirements for a given problem.

Comment: Add the argument `keep = FALSE` to `parse` to get an approximately 3x speedup.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I love you

Comment: REOPEN, I have been looking on this topic everywhere and I have not find anywhere good suggestions. This for me was a very complex problem and the only way I found was to store conditions as text. Even a reply on why this is not good or possible alternatives could be valuable for me and the community.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The argument is `keep.source`, not `keep`.

Comment: There’s no way around the slowness of parsing millions of strings, it’s inherent in the complexity hidden behind `parse`. What you *can* (and should) do is to avoid parsing them repeatedly. Do you really have millions of input strings that are evaluated only once? More likely you have a handful of strings that get evaluated over and over again.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the arguments proposed by Grothendieck is a big improvement and does make my solution viable. Anyway I am trying to reduce the parsing as much as possible. I have posted the approach I am using it in the question as an answer to your comment

Comment: @thc can you provide a simple example of what you mean?

Comment: @MrFlick I've provided more context to my problem. Do you see any step having a conceptual error?

Comment: In response to your edit: the problem is that you still generate *strings* that need to be re-parsed inside the loop every time. That’s a lot of redundant work. You should change your code such that you call `parse` only *once* per expression, and then just call `eval` inside the loop on the already-parsed expression, and with an environment containing the current values. This will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thank you. I see it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226311/discussion-between-gerald-t-and-konrad-rudolph).